# Allow user to cancel task running in BackgroundService

Tags: asp.net-core, background-task, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I created a background service to process items in a queue as demonstrated here:

[Queued Background Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks)

Unlike the example, items are added to the queue via a Web API method that looks something like this:

```
[HttpPut("queueworkitem")]
public async Task<ActionResult> QueueWorkItem() {
    var collection = GetALargeCollection();
    await _taskQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(async token => {
        foreach (var item in collection) {
           //do work here
        }
    });
    return Ok();
}
```

I would like to provide a way for a caller to cancel a queued task in a subsequent request using a reference returned by QueueWorkItem.  I tried the following, but CancellationTokenSource is not serializable.  Is there some way to accomplish this?

```
[HttpPut("queueworkitem")]
public async Task<ActionResult> QueueWorkItem() {
    var collection = GetALargeCollection();
    var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var cancellationToken = source.Token;

    await _taskQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(async token => {
       foreach (var item in collection) {
           cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
           //do work here
       }
    });
    return Ok(source);
}

[HttpPut("cancelworkitem")]
public Task<ActionResult> CancelWorkItem(CancellationTokenSource source) {
    source.Cancel();
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Keep the CancellationTokenSource around in something like IMemoryCache and pass the cache key to the client?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @BenderBoy. Not sure if if it's the best solution, but it does work, and I am able to remove the item from cache and dispose of the CancellationTokenSource when the process completes, so don't have to worry about cache expiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your cancellation token inside your task queue and use a unique key to find it later, for example:

create a `WorkItem` class/record to keep everything in one place:

```cs
public record WorkItem(Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask> func, string key, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource);
```

then you can store this key/token inside a dictionary:
for example:

```cs
public class BackgroundTaskQueue : IBackgroundTaskQueue
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, CancellationTokenSource> _tokenSources;
    private readonly Channel<WorkItem> _queue;

    public BackgroundTaskQueue(int capacity = 100)
    {
        var options = new BoundedChannelOptions(capacity)
        {
            FullMode = BoundedChannelFullMode.Wait
        };
        _queue = Channel.CreateBounded<WorkItem>(options);
        _tokenSources = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, CancellationTokenSource>();
    }

    public bool CancelWorkItem(string key)
    {
        var exist = _tokenSources.TryRemove(key, out var tokenSource);
        if (!exist) return false; // token source not found

        tokenSource!.Cancel();
        return true;
    }

    public async ValueTask QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(WorkItem workItem)
    {
        _tokenSources.TryAdd(workItem.Key, workItem.TokenSource);
        await _queue.Writer.WriteAsync(workItem);
    }

    public async ValueTask<WorkItem> DequeueAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var workItem = await _queue.Reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken);
        return workItem;
    }
}
```

At the end, you can use it this way in your API:

```cs
[HttpGet("queueworkitem")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> QueueWorkItem()
    {
        var key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token; 
        
        await _taskQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(new WorkItem(async (token) =>
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && !token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Processing ... {key}");
                await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
            } 
        }, key, tokenSource));
        
        return Ok(key);
    }
    
    
    [HttpGet("cancelworkitem")]
    public ActionResult CancelWorkItem(string token_key)
    {
        if (_taskQueue.CancelWorkItem(token_key))
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        return BadRequest("Task not found");
    }
```

This will work fine if you have only 1 server and you don't want to serialize and save your tasks in some storage. but if you need to run the tasks later, I would suggest checking out the Hangfire library which gives you exactly the same functionalities.

Comment: Thanks @AliReza Sabouri!  Definitely like this approach better.  Store the CancellationTokenSource inside BackgroundTaskQueue rather than making persistence the concern of the consumer.  Good catch also on needing to check the primary cancellation token passed down by the BackgroundService!

Comment: Good to hear it works for you, happy to help.